# matlab error minus , matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

Hi why am i getting this error?

```
x = linspace(-1,1,20);
y = linspace(-2,2,40);
z = (1.+sin(pi.*x)).*((3.+cos(1.065.*y)).^2).*exp(-x.^2 -(y.^2)./4);
```

??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `x` and `y` are not the same size.  What you likely want to use here is `meshgrid`.

The code would be something like:

```
      [x,y] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,20),linspace(-2,2,40));
      z = (1.+sin(pi.*x)).*((3.+cos(1.065.*y)).^2).*exp(-x.^2 -(y.^2)./4);
```

Then you can visualize like:

```
      surf(x,y,z)
```

And get stuff like this:

[image]